# Windows 10 Anniversary update fails on Education version

Tags: windows-10, updates

I try to install the anniversary update on my *Windows 10 x64* operating system, but it fails with error code

> 0xa0000400

I already tried update with *Media creation tool*, and *Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant* but with no success. Current version of my operating system is **10586**. Windows Update says that there my operating system is up to date.

**Media creation tool:**

[image: Media creation tool]

I set back the language to English, restarted my machine, but I still received the same error.

**Windows 10 Update Assistant:**

[image: Windows 10 Update Assistant]

I am the only one who is receiving this error? Someone know a solution?

**Edit:**

Finally i have downloaded it from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO/ more precise from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/vlacademicwindows10

Comment: Your receiving the error because your using a tool not meant for the version of Windows 10 you have installed.

Comment: But on the download page wasn't an option to choose the target OS.

Comment: @C1sco Windows 10 Edication ISOs can only be download at the VLK website.....

Comment: I Don't understand why i cant simply update it with Windows update why is education version so special?

Comment: Because it's a VLK product.  How you update it to Version 1607 is different, specifically you have to use the ISO, to do so.  Same for Enterprise...

Comment: [here](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx) is the correct website for an Version 1607 Education ISO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool can be only used to download Windows 10 Home/Pro (N)/Singe Language Editions and not the Education.

Get the ISO via MSDNAA/Dreamspark or wait until you get the Update offered via Windows Update. Microsoft releases the updates in waves to make sure the servers are not hammered too much.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've downloaded it from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/vlacademicwindows10